# Orbits of $SL_{n}(q)$ on pairs of $k$-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, determinant, finite-fields

Let $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ be two pairs of $k$-subspaces of a vector space of dimension $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, with $k\leq n$ and $\mathrm{dim}(A\cap B)=\mathrm{dim}(C\cap D)$. Does there exist an element $g\in \mathrm{SL}_{n}(q)$ which sends $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $D$?

I know there is a similar question at:
[Prove two pairs of subspaces are in the same orbit using dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/prove-two-pairs-of-subspaces-are-in-the-same-orbit-using-dimension) which asks the same but for $GL_{n}(q)$. From there, I know that there exists $g\in GL_{n}(q)$ which sends $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $D$, but how can I adjust this element to have determinant 1?

Many thanks.

Comment: If $\det g = d$, wouldn't multiplying one column by $\pm d^{-1}$ work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose such a $g\in GL_n(q)$.  Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis for the vector space such that $\{e_1,\dots,e_k\}$ is a basis for $A$ and $\{e_\ell,\dots,e_{\ell+k-1}\}$ is a basis for $B$ for some $\ell$.  Now let $h\in GL_n(q)$ be the map that sends $e_1$ to $\det(g)^{-1}e_1$ and fixes $e_m$ for all $m>1$.  Note that $h$ sends $A$ to $A$ and $B$ to $B$, and $\det(h)=\det(g)^{-1}$.  Thus $gh$ sends $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $D$, and $\det(gh)=1$.